# Selective parsing of CSV file in HTML

Tags: html, csv, fgetcsv

I have VB program which generates a CSV file and updates it every second. I've used a CSV to HTML parser to display the CSV data in a table in an HTML page. 
The problem I'm facing is, I want only selective data from the CSV to be displayed according to users request can someone suggest as to how to approach the solution.

Comment: Please can you provide some code illustrating how you are currently displaying the data?

Comment: For this CSV file, what are you using to parse it to HTML?

Comment: I've used the method shown in this link to parse the csv file http://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823